# libsnmp-perl 20.04 can not install

Tags: 20.04, perl, snmp

I can not install package **libsnmp-perl**.

I hope that the text I pasted is helpful.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Using `sudo apt-get install libsnmp-perl` gives the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsnmp-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.1) but 5.30.0-9build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

(added)

Using `apt-cache policy perl`:

```
perl:
  Installed: 5.30.0-9build1
  Candidate: 5.30.0-9build1
  Version table:
  *** 5.30.0-9build1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1258809/edit) to include the complete output of `apt-cache policy perl`

Comment: Got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

List available versions:

```
sudo apt list libsnmp-perl -a
Listing... Done
libsnmp-perl/focal-updates,focal-security 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2]
libsnmp-perl/focal,now 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.1]
```

and install not last:

```
sudo apt install libsnmp-perl=5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2
```

Works for me.

Comment: does not work. i get the same as above. but: the required perl  is installed already:
     perl is already the newest version (5.30.0-9build1).
and for your hint:
    sudo apt install libsnmp-perl=5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    libsnmp-perl is already the newest version (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2).
    libsnmp-perl set to manually installed.
so the problem mentioned is not solved

Comment: There is new version: 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.2

Comment: yep, installed now fine.